# Set border around imageview with no background in javafx

Tags: button, javafx, imageview, javafx-8, javafx-css

I would like to have a button or a clickable ImageView in my program. When clicked i would like to have a border to appear in a shape of the imageview. This image had no background, but i can't find a way to specify the border's shape. For example:

[image]

This image has no background, and the border has to be only around the image so no rectangles or circles. Is this possible?

Comment: You can draw 2 images. 1 with borders and 1 without and swap them on hoover or click

Comment: That would be possible, but will that be smooth enough?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may prefer to use `DropShadow` effect to show border:

```
@Override
public void start( final Stage primaryStage )
{
    DropShadow ds = new DropShadow( 20, Color.AQUA );
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView( "http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/forgeofempires/images/b/b8/Castel_del_Monte.png" );

    imageView.setOnMouseClicked( ( MouseEvent event ) ->
    {
        imageView.requestFocus();
    } );

    imageView.focusedProperty().addListener(( ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue ) ->
    {
        if ( newValue )
        {
            imageView.setEffect( ds );
        }
        else
        {
            imageView.setEffect( null );
        }
    });

    final Scene scene = new Scene( 
            new VBox( imageView, 
            new Button( "When you focus on me, the imageview looses its shadow effect" ) ), 
            500, 200 );
    primaryStage.setScene( scene );
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

When the imageview is clicked we request a focus on it, which triggers the `focusProperty` change listener and sets the effect, and when the imageview looses its focus (either by hitting TAB or clicking the below button) the effect cleared.

Comment: Thank you that was exactly what i needed. I did not know about the dropshadow.